# building a computer: GA-Z87X-UD3H does not recognize 2hdds 1 ssd and 1 dvd drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard, sata

I have never built a computer before and followed these instructions for the 1200 rig:
http://lifehacker.com/5840963/the-best-pcs-you-can-build-for-600-and-1200

When I booted it up, I got the following error:
[image]

I tried plugging in the different drives (one of them has an operating system on it) into the different sata ports on the motherboard. Then I realized that the sata drives also needed power, so I tried hooking up the power to what looked like the graphics card power outlet. I tried that but it didn't change anything. As of now, the dvd burner does not respond to anything -- I am trying to boot the computer into a cd for now.

Here is the power line from the sata drives (I am holding it):
[image]

More pictures of the rig:
[image]

Is there anything wrong with the way I assembled the build? The graphics card seems to be falling off -- does it need to be secured in another way? I only plugged the power into it because I did not find another place to plug it into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not **outlets** on the graphics card, they are **inputs**. Modern PCI-E graphics cards require one or two six-pin or eight-pin power inputs direct from your power supply. Modern (mid-to-high-end at least) graphics cards do not draw power from the motherboard.

Your SATA drives also draw power directly from the power supply; your power supply should have several SATA power cables, they have a long, thin, L-shaped slot on one end.

There should be **no** cables connecting your graphics card to your SATA drives, especially not power cables.

Comment: awesome! just got it to work!my graphics card is put into the pci slot (it is high-end i think). is that the appropriate place? also -- i was able to connect a cable form the power supply to the left socket (the 6pin one) and nothing is in the 8pin one. Is this OK?

Comment: You'll want to connect both. The card will only draw as much as it needs, so basic computing will work fine with just one connector.  But if you start up a graphics intensive application (such as a game) and the card doesn't have enough power you system will crash.

Comment: oh ok. thanks! just found the other connector. What about the placement of the graphics card into the PCI 3 slot? and it being supported only on 2 sides -- the connection to the motherboard and an attachment to the case, but not on the 3rd side or 4th?